# AWS Lambda Function not read input json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

My code can not correct read JSON input.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    WEBHOOK_URL = "https://" + os.environ['WEBHOOK_URL']

    sns        = event['Records'][0]['Sns']
    json_msg   = json.loads(sns['Message'])

    region     = sns['TopicArn'].split(':')[3]
    status     = json_msg['NewStateValue']

    message    =  'region: ' + region + '\n' + 'status: ' + status

    payload = {
        "username": "bot",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": str(message)
            }
        ]
    }

    r = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, json=payload)
    return r.status_code
```

I get a region, but I don't' get status. Example JSON input: https://github.com/builtinnya/aws-sns-slack-terraform/blob/51b954ca8f736e08deccd4196670a187f7b58fe5/sns-to-slack/lambda_function.py#L278

Answer (score 1):

use below lines:-

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 WEBHOOK_URL = "https://" + os.environ['WEBHOOK_URL']

    sns        = event['Records'][0]['Sns']
    json_msg   = json.loads(sns['Message'])

    region     = sns['TopicArn'].split(':')[3]
    status     = json_msg['NewStateValue']

    message    =  'region: ' + region + '\n' + 'status: ' + status

    payload = {
        "username": "bot",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": str(message)
            }
        ]
    }

    r = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, json=payload)
    response = {
            "statusCode": r.status_code,
            "body": json.dumps("Your message")
        }
    return response
```

Comment: i use:

from __future__ import print_function

import os
import json
import base64
import re
import requests.....but nothing

Comment: Check modified answer

Comment: I got some joke because of real JSON which go to AWS topic get me the result, but test JSON work only in Lambda-manual-test. I got JSON but I have inside dict and I can parse this dict: alarm_name  = out.get('AlarmName')

Comment: What are you trying to say now? @AlexanderSKyzZz

Comment: Example JSON input for AWS SNS topic's doesn't work.